# Allow Unauthenticated users to only read data from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a flutter app in which I want users to only read data without authenticating themselves with firebase auth. Is there a way? I tried the below code.

```
        rules_version = '2';
           service cloud.firestore {
          match /databases/{database}/documents {
             match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: true;
    }
  }
}
```

But firebase has been giving me warnings that my database is not secure every day. Is there a way to let users only read data from firestore without Unsecuring your firestore database?

Answer (score 1):

Provide `if true` to enable all to read and write.

> Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true; // all can read
      allow write: if request.auth != null;  // only auth user can write
    }
  }
}
```

More and ref [firebase-firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#auth-required)

Comment: Thank you @Yeasin I tried it. I am not receiving any warning from firebase and i am able to read documents without auth.